# minimal generating set for given set of strings

Tags: combinatorics, computational-complexity

Given a set of strings $H$, I wish to find a minimal size set of strings $G$ that "generates" $H$ in the sense that any string in $H$ can be formed by concatenating strings from $G$ ($G$ can be $H$ itself, so we have $|H|$ as upper bound).

For example, if $H=<abef,abeg,acef,aceg,adef,adeg>$ then $G=<ab,ac,ad,ef,eg>$ generates $H$ and has size 5 which is minimal. $G'=<abe,ace,ade,f,g>$ is also a generating set with size 5.

If $H=<ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd>$ than $G=<a,b,c,d>$ generates $H$ and has size 4 which is minimal.

Is it NP hard?

Comment: Every free group on countably many generators is isomorphic to a subgroup of $F_2$, the free group on two generators -- this is because $[F_2, F_2]$ is free on $\aleph_0$ generators.

Comment: If you're looking for something more combinatorial (involving the actual strings you chose for the generators), you'll need to make your question more precise.

Comment: NP-hardness is a property of decision problems ("given $x$, is $x \in X$?" for some interesting set $X$). You seem to be asking about a function problem ("given $x$, calculate $f(x)$" for some interesting function $f$).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have edited the question

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Am I right in understanding that this is not about groups any more: when you say $G$ generates $H$, you just mean that each string in $H$ can be formed by concatenating strings in $G$? (Aside: you have not addressed my comment about NP-hardness.)

Comment: Yes, I thought it was the same

Comment: it is a decision problem, given a set H and G, you have to decide if G is a minimal size generating set of H

Comment: You should reword your question to make that clear. "Given *foo*, I wish to find *bar*" reads like a function problem.

Comment: You can say the same about MAX-CLIQUE problem, but still it is a decision problem. I am interested in the generating set, not just the minimal size of it.

Comment: Related: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50602/covering-a-set-of-paths-with-a-smaller-set-of-paths